# CakePHP, .htaccess, more than one application in the same root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

i have a problem here...

i need to launch a web site that i developed at the one server that is windows server, and at there has one application that i can not remove or change it and it is an asp application, but that is not exactly the problem. My app is a CakePHP application and i need to do it work in the same folder than other app  that i said, so my Cake is redirecting everything in the URL to webroot, it is normal, but the o other application is in the folder "/admin", when i try to access "mydomain.com/admin" it is redirected to cake app. So, i need to put in my .htaccess some rule for when the URL is "/admin" don't rewrite, but no affect any URL different of that.

Anyone have an idea?

Here is the default .htaccess of CakePHP:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule      ^$ app/webroot/     [L]
   RewriteRule      (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule   ^$   admin/   [L]
    RewriteRule   (.*) admin/$1   [L]
</IfModule>
```